# blockscout unable to get block information on initial execution

Tags: docker-compose, blockchain, go-ethereum

I'm building a POA network in a local environment.

After completing the connection to eth-netstats, I connected blockscout and checked http://localhost:4000, and I couldn't get the information about the blocks that were previously created. What's the problem?

this is my docker-compose.yml file but, blockscout is not working

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  eth-netstats:
    image: kamael/eth-netstats
    container_name: eth-netstats
    depends_on:
      - node1
    ports:
      - '8080:3000'
    environment:
      - WS_SECRET=CROFFLE
    networks:
      - croffle-network

  node1:
    image: ethereum/client-go
    container_name: node1
    command: --datadir="/root/.ethereum"
      --ethstats=node1:CROFFLE@eth-netstats:3000
      --syncmode="full"
      --port=30301
      --http
      --http.addr="0.0.0.0"
      --http.port=8501
      --http.corsdomain="*"
      --http.api="admin,eth,miner,net,txpool,personal,web3"
      --ws
      --ws.addr="0.0.0.0"
      --ws.port=8502
      --ws.api "admin,eth,miner,net,txpool,personal,web3"
      --networkid=255
      --unlock="cf766f1581c6246c8f491283fbc3ca839e6cfba3"
      --password=/root/.ethereum/password
      --miner.gasprice=0
      --miner.etherbase="cf766f1581c6246c8f491283fbc3ca839e6cfba3"
      --allow-insecure-unlock
      --ipcdisable
      --nodiscover
      --mine
    volumes:
      - ./node1:/root/.ethereum:rw
    ports:
      - '30301:30301'
      - '8501:8501'
      - '8502:8502'
    networks:
      - croffle-network

  redis_db:
    extends:
      file: ./services/docker-compose-redis.yml
      service: redis_db

  db:
    extends:
      file: ./services/docker-compose-db.yml
      service: db

  smart-contract-verifier:
    extends:
      file: ./services/docker-compose-smart-contract-verifier.yml
      service: smart-contract-verifier

  visualizer:
    extends:
      file: ./services/docker-compose-visualizer.yml
      service: visualizer

  sig-provider:
    extends:
      file: ./services/docker-compose-sig-provider.yml
      service: sig-provider

  blockscout:
    depends_on:
      - eth-netstats
      - node1
      - redis_db
      - db
      - smart-contract-verifier
    image: blockscout/blockscout:${DOCKER_TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        COIN: 'CROFFLE'
        CACHE_EXCHANGE_RATES_PERIOD: ''
        DISABLE_READ_API: 'false'
        ETHEREUM_JSONRPC_HTTP_URL: http://localhost:8501
        API_PATH: '/'
        NETWORK_PATH: '/'
        DISABLE_WEBAPP: 'false'
        DISABLE_WRITE_API: 'false'
        CACHE_ENABLE_TOTAL_GAS_USAGE_COUNTER: ''
        CACHE_ADDRESS_WITH_BALANCES_UPDATE_INTERVAL: ''
        SOCKET_ROOT: '/'
        WOBSERVER_ENABLED: 'false'
        ADMIN_PANEL_ENABLED: ''
    # restart: always
    container_name: 'blockscout'
    links:
      - db:database
    command: bash -c "bin/blockscout eval \"Elixir.Explorer.ReleaseTasks.create_and_migrate()\" && bin/blockscout start"
    extra_hosts:
      - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
    env_file:
      - ./envs/common-blockscout.env
    ports:
      - 4000:4000

networks:
  croffle-network:
    driver: bridge
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl2Lf.png)